# Mule: Processing messages in intervals. Delayed message processing

Tags: mule, delayed-execution

How do I create a delayed JMS message processor in Mule 3.3.1? My goal is to process messages from a queue in certain interval...some listener that wakes up every minute to process messages.

I have the following configuration, but the delay is not honored. When a message is rolled back, it is immediately picked for processing.

```
    <spring:bean id="MQConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <spring:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
        <spring:property name="hostName" value="myHost"/>
        <spring:property name="port" value="1414"/>
        <spring:property name="queueManager" value="myQmgr"/>
    </spring:bean>

<jms:connector name="queueConnector" connectionFactory-ref="MQConnectionFactory" 
            specification="1.1" username="xxx" password="yyy" 
            disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"
            numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="3" maxRedelivery="5">
            <service-overrides transactedMessageReceiver="com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver"/>
</jms:connector>

<jms:endpoint name="someQueue" queue="osmQueue" connector-ref="queueConnector">
  <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>          
  <property key="pollingFrequency" value="60000"/> 
</jms:endpoint>
```

I did a lot of search but am unable to indentify a proper solution. If there is a better option, I'm open. Appreciate any help. 2 days and no response? Did I phrase the question wrong?

Comment: can you share your MQConnectionFactory configuration? Also I can see that you are configuring the transactedMessageReceiver although no transaction is being used, so it probably won't be used anyway

Comment: @genjosanzo. Updated MQConnectionFactory. Thanks. You mention "no transaction is being used"....but I do use jms:transaction, could you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Quartz?
This config fires up your JMS inbound every minute

```
<flow name="ftpFlow2" doc:name="ftpFlow2">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="job1" repeatInterval="60000" responseTimeout="10000"     doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="someQueue"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```